# receiver 'class' or 'interface' expected error in manifest

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, receiver

I wrote a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`, and declared a Receiver in the manifest.

There is a red underline that says `class` or `interface` expected".

My class was defined as follows:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: TEST");
    }
}
```

This was how I declared the receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have gone through each SO link that has a similar question, and attempted/checked all of the following, none of which worked:

1. I checked to make sure I had the required methods in the BroadcastReceiver class
2. I checked to make sure I didn't have mismatched brackets in the class, and close it too soon
3. I tried writing out the name of the class in multiple ways when declaring it in the manifest:

> ```
> android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
> android:name="com.claire.myapp.MyBroadcastReceiver"
> android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver"
> ```

Does anybody have a clue as to why none of these are being recognized in the manifest? Or why Android Studio is convinced that `MyBroadcastReceiver` isn't a class?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is `MyBroadcastReceiver` is inner class?

Comment: It is an outer class, with nothing else in it except the onRecieve method

Comment: Is <receiver> <receiver/> within <application></application> tag?

Comment: Yes, <receiver> is inside the <application> tags, I have also tried it outside <application> tag, while still inside <manifest> and neither have worked.

Comment: post your full manifest file, post image screenshot showing path where you have added MyBroadcastReceiver.java in you src folder.

Comment: Here is the full manifest file: https://pasteboard.co/HauqAO4.png
Here is the location of MyBroadcastReceiver.java in the project: https://pasteboard.co/Haur1vk.png

Comment: @ClaireLi Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that the package in which you are developing is the development package , not the test packages. 
just check the package name ,maybe manifest is not able to find that class in your package .

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that I am in the the development package, and not the packages for (Test) or (androidTest). I have also confirmed I wrote the package name correctly

Comment: can you please share the complete manifest file with screen shot .

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the full manifest file: https://pasteboard.co/HauqAO4.png

Comment: found it  .. just take your broadcast receiver inside your application tag

Comment: <application> </application>

Comment: <application
        <receiver android:name=".Login.NetworkReciever"></receiver>
    </application>

Comment: I have moved it inside the application tags, but am getting the same error. I have taken a screenshot of the changed manifest: https://pasteboard.co/HaypOnL.png

Answer (score 0):

Use a fully qualified Receiver class name i.e., with a package name

```
<receiver android:name="<packagename>.MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I have written out the full package name to the receiver, but I am still getting the same error. Here is a screenshot of the result: https://pasteboard.co/HaypOnL.png